# How to open the color input's dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, input, drop-down-menu

In opera the color input is supported. It's a dropdown list, where you can select a color. But how can I open this dropdown list with JS?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this a <select> list?

Comment: no. It's <input type="color" />

Comment: the problem with this, is in fact the same problem with "opening" a select menu, that is the UA (browser) could potentially render the element any way it chooses. So there is no way to say "open sub-menu" because there is no guarantee that the element in question will be rendered using a sub-menu... (it technically could be represented as ANYTHING).. however if you are looking for an Opera specific "hack" to open it, I would try playing with `.click()` or its focus in general, or perhaps looking for a custom Opera "method" that allows you to open it (unlikely)

Answer (score -1):

You can use a js color picker [like this example](http://javascript.html.it/demo/javascript/4541/esempio.htm) you can also dowload the source code
[Here](http://javascript.html.it/script/vedi/4541/color-picker/)